# Azure function app is not triggering while calling from deployed web app

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have created an httpTrigger azure function and trying to access it from my azure web app. Both the web app and azure function belongs to the same resource group.

While calling the published azure function from post man and localhost it is working perfectly without any issues. After publishing the web app to azure, I am getting an error

> 'No such host is known'

. The function trigger is not at all visible in Monitor tab

Web app call

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(functionRequest), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);
        var status = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

Azure function app

```
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
             [DurableClient] IDurableClient starter,
            ILogger log, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
        }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: are you connecting to a database?

Comment: 'No such host is known' usually means that your deployment had issues. You can troubleshoot this through the portal to get to the root of the error. If you post more relevant code I can spot check it.

Comment: @lopezbertoni- I have already posted the client call and function signature, What kind of deployment error you suspect?

Comment: @Sajeetharan No

Comment: how you are invoking the function? what is the url?

Comment: i think the URL is not correct. Also, can you confirm the function is displayed in functions blade at Azure portal.

Comment: @user1672994 It is visible in the blade. I have taken the url from azure function - get function url

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1140). Are you on the latest SDK?

Comment: @AliasVarghese are you using DI? How are you loading your configuration? Is this consumption plan? Premium plan? Have you tried looking at logs in the portal?

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help. I found the issue. The url I got from the azure function blade was private url, which works from localhost even postman. But I had to get public url using gateway, That works for azure too

Answer (score 1):

I try to create `DurableClient` Trigger, and test it in portal but not in web app, and it works for me.

So I think you should change your `url` in `var status = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;`. And you will solve the issue.

After request the url which from `Get function URL`. You will get `id`,`statusQueryGetUri`,`sendEventPostUri`,`terminatePostUri`,`purgeHistoryDeleteUri`. For more details, you can refer to [the offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api).

[image]

**You can get something you want from `statusQueryGetUri`.**

[image]